# Is there any free News feed api available for displaying News?

Tags: ios, ios4

I am implementing one News feed related application.I am finding free api which provides day to day different types of News like:

1. Technology
2. Business
3. Political
4. etc.

Comment: yes using rss also we can do right?

Comment: Find yourself an RSS feed that you like (or aggregate them in Google Reader or something) for each of the sections you want, then write/copy an RSS renderer for your app.

Comment: yes i have found the RSS feed from google.now only one thing is remaining that is rss feed for stock market if possible then share the link.Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found some News feed which are listed below.

Google News Feeds

Top News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss

world News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=w&output=rss

India News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=in&topic=n&output=rss

Business News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=b&output=rss

Tech/Sci News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=t&output=rss

Health News:   http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=m&output=rss

Sports News:    http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=s&output=rss

Comment: Where did I find reference about query string parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One of website i found which give all categories wise news Api

Click [1]: https://newsapi.org